# Is there any default views in couchbase?

Tags: java, couchbase

I like to retrieve all documents with document name starting with "user-". I know it can be done using n1ql. But I read n1ql is slow so I would like to use a faster method . In couchbase web console there is an option to provide start key and filter documents by document name. So I wonder if there is a default view in couchbase which we can use.

Below is the url called when I filtered in web console.

```
 IP:8091/pools/default/buckets/bucketname/docs?startkey="user-"&inclusive_end=false&skip=0&include_docs=true&limit=6&_=1481092177210
```

Comment: Don't believe everything you read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, N1QL is not slow, especially not for these kind of queries.
if you need all documents you can use the primaryScan (which is the default index). or you can get all the keys from the query and get all documents with bulk processing.
The RestAPI you've located is not exposed by the View mechanism (port 8092) and it is not supported for you to use in you APP via the SDK. Although you can use that rest endpoint to query your docs, it is not really maintained in the same way views are. The syntax is the same as the views, but internally - it is a different.

You can use it if you want to get all docs, and it should be accurate, but you will have to parse it by your own and **we can't promise future compatibility.**

So no, there are no default or built in views in Couchbase you can use.